# How to solve the equation $x^{10}+11x^{5}+29=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Q$)$**Solve the equation : $x^{10}+11x^{5}+29=0$**

Ans) My approach:

$x^{10}+11x^{5}+29=0$

Let's substitute $x^{5}=u$.

$\implies u^{2}+11u+29=0$

$\implies u=\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $u=\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$\implies x^{5}=\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $x^{5}=\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$\implies x^{5}-(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{5}=0$ and $x^{5}-(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{5}=0$

$\implies (x-\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}})[x^{4}+x^{3}\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}}+x^{2}(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{2}+x(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{3}+(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{4}]=0$

and

$(x-\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}})[x^{4}+x^{3}\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}}+x^{2}(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{2}+x(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{3}+(\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}})^{4}]=0$

Finally I can find only $2$ values of $x$ i.e. $x=\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$
and $x=\sqrt[5]{\frac{-11-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$

I can't find out the remaining $8$ values of $x$. Please help me out. I am mainly facing problem in factorizing the  expression to find the remaining $8$ values of $x$ .

Comment: This question was asked by a student of our Engineering college to the Professors. So, I am also interested in solving this equation.

Comment: Are you familar with roots of unity?

Comment: Do you know the solution to $x^5-1=0$?

Comment: You found two real roots. The other roots are complex.

Comment: Specifically: Consider the factorization $(x^5 + 11/2)^2 -5/4$ and then use the roots of unity approach.

Comment: I removed the [tag:linear-algebra] tag

Comment: "I can't find out the remaining 8 values of x"  What makes you think there 10 real roots?  You've have completely found the only two possible values of $u$ as $u_1$ and $u_2$ and so all the solutions will be the solutions to $x^5= u_1$ and $x^5=u_2$ and $x^{odd} = k$ we each have only one root $x=\sqrt[odd]{k}$. So that's it. This expression only has two real roots.  A polynomial of degree $k$ *may* have up to $k$ real roots but it could have fewer.  If you know complex numbers though, it will have $k$ complex roots and $x^{10}+11x^{5}+29=0$ has $2$ real roots and eight complex non-real roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other $8$ values of $x$ are complex numbers and can be found via Euler's formula. If $r$ is any real number and $n$ an integer, then $r^{\frac{1}{n}}=|r^{\frac{1}{n}}|e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ for integer values of $k$ such that $0\leq k\leq n-1$, which when collected constitute all the $n^{th}$ roots of $r$. You have found the roots corresponding to $k=0$ for both of your numbers. Now all you need to do is plug in the other values for $k$ into the formula. It may also help to know that $|r^{\frac{1}{n}}|e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}=|r^{\frac{1}{n}}|(\operatorname{cos}(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+i\operatorname{sin}(\frac{2k\pi}{n}))$, to keep the results nice and tidy.